VPSにSSH接続する手続きは、OSインストール後に改めて行うのですか？　それともインストールと同時に行うのですか？
VPSにSSH接続する時、一般的にはどのような流れになるのでしょうか？
環境
・さくらVPS
・CentOS Stream 9 インストール
・Rloginターミナル
最初に試したこと
さくらVPSに「CentOS Stream 9」インストール後、Rloginターミナル経由でSSH接続しようとしたのですが、(後から公開鍵をコントロールパネルへコピペしても)認証エラーとなりました。
最終的に
「CentOS Stream 9」を再インストールしたのですが、再インストールする際の設定オプションで、予めWindowsで作成した公開鍵をコピペしたら、SSH接続できました。
質問
・VPSにSSH接続する手続きは、OSインストール後に改めて行うのですか？　それともインストールと同時に行うのですか？
・OSインストール後にSSH接続する手続きを行う場合は、VPSのコンソール画面か何かを使用して何らかの設定を行うのですか？

参考: https://manual.sakura.ad.jp/vps/support/security/firstsecurity.html#ssh

業界標準の「一般的」というものはありません。あるのは、各社が勝手に自分たちの都合で作ったで手順だけです。さくらVPSでのやり方はさくらVPSのヘルプを見て、それでもわからない、エラーになるなどの場合はサポートに問い合わせてください。さくらVPSの社員でない限り、公開されているヘルプ以上の事は誰も回答できません。また、さくらVPSのやり方が他のVPSでも同じである場合もあれば、異なる場合もあります。サービス毎に異なりますので、各社のヘルプを必ず参照してください。
